# Initial Check to see if a Substring is within range

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am in the beginnings of learning C++ and I am wondering if there is a way to assert that a substring can be created from a String, given a range. My String will vary in size each iteration. I am trying to create six substrings from that original String. With this variation in size, I am sometimes trying to access indexes of the String that do not exist for that particular iteration.

For example, if my String in iteration 1 is 11 characters
My first substring is from 3 characters - valid
My second substring is the next 3 characters - valid
My third substring is the next 5 characters - valid
My fourth substring is the next 4 characters - not valid - crashes program
My fifth substring - not valid, out of range
My sixth substring - not valid, out of range

I am wondering if there is a small check I can do to assert the length is valid. It's worth noting, I suppose, that I have not set any default values to these substrings. They are declared as:

string subS1
string subS2
string subS3
...
...
string subS6

Would setting all 6 substrings to null upon declaration alleviate this issue and for any valid substring, the value will just be overwritten?

Thanks in advance

```
 subS1 = str.substr(0, 3); // Could be valid range
 subS2 = str.substr(3, 3);  // Could be valid range
 subS3 = str.substr(6, 5);  // Could be valid range
 subS4 = str.substr(11, 4); // Could be valid range
 subS5 = str.substr(15, 4); // Could be valid range
 subS6 = str.substr(19); // from the nineteenth character to the end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have example code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added some lines of how I am making the substrings.

Comment: check string size before call `str.substr(index, size)` like `subs1 = str.size() > 0 ? str.substr(0, 3) : "";`

Comment: This should be exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm--->**

**step 1:** Get the length of string in current iteration in variable **size.**

**step 2:**   Write this code in itertaion.

```
         int i=0;
         i= str.substr(start,end).length();
         if( i>size) then,
         std::cout<<"index exceeded";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either check the size of `str` before extracting the string, or rely on [std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)'s `len` parameter:

> Number of characters to include in the substring (if the string is
>   shorter, as many characters as possible are used). A value of
>   string::npos indicates all characters until the end of the string.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str="Alexander the Great";

  std::string str2 = str.substr (16, 25);

  std::cout << str2 << '\n'; // eat

  return 0;
}
```

It won't crash, it will just use as many characters as possible.

This however:

```
std::string str2 = str.substr (20, 25);
```

should crash, so do it like this in this case:

```
std::string str2 = ""; // initialise to empty string, that is the NULL you are saying I guess
if(str.size() > 20)
  str2 = str.substr (20, 25);
// 'str2' will be an empty string
```